# How to ban scripts using chrome.contentSettings API while allow content scripts in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a tool for DOM content extraction purpose. So I implemented a simple chrome extension using client script, to allow using click to select desired element and extract it.

And I want to use these data (eg. the path to the element) for batch work, which suppose to be easy to use with wget and some other tools. But the problem is. as the web page I used to pick element are changed by scripts on it, so the paths turned out to be wrong, as the wget won't execute scripts.

To solve this problem I tried to block javascript using chrome.contentSettings API, but accidently, it blocks content script as well (at least event handling part, because other parts of my code is executed). Is there any way to solve this like using an exception rule or using some other approaches to block the script on the web page?

Here is the background script used to ban javascript on the target host.

```
var contentSettings = chrome.contentSettings;

contentSettings.javascript.clear({}, function() {

contentSettings.javascript.set({
  primaryPattern: '*://*.example.com/*',
  setting: 'block'
});

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `chrome.contentSettings` API cannot fulfill this need.

Instead using `chrome.webRequest` API could solve this problem easily, though it has other limitations like can't block inline scripts in the web page.

Here is the background script that could do the trick.

```
var matches = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].matches;
var pattern = new RegExp('^https?:\\/\\/(\\w+\\.)?(' +
    matches.map(function(pattern) {
      return RegExp.escape(pattern.substring(6, pattern.length - 2));
    }).join('|') + ')\\/', 'i');

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
  return {
    cancel: details.requestHeaders.some(function(header) {
      if (header.name == 'Referer' && pattern.test(header.value))
        return true;
    })
  };
}, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
  types: ['script']
}, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']);
```